# Facebook Web Scraping on public post

Tags: facebook-graph-api, web-scraping, automation

As you know, Facebook stop search public post functionality on their Graph API with the arrival of 2.0 version (which was release the October 1st, 2014).

BUT (^^), i absolutely need this functionality because a part of my work requires recurrently search on public post.

It's so boring and alienating that i decide to try to develop a web scraping program for scrap information on public post.

The hardest part of this is to manage the infinite scroll page, so i try to find how to go to the next page.

With many tests i finally find that the element that determines the next page is a variable name "cursor" and not the variable "page_number" as one might think (we can change the page_number variable but nothing happen).

But the problem is that the variable seems encryt (below an example of what does it look like), so i'm stuck here...

A genius or a hero can give me a solution ? Or the problem can't be resolve ?

Thank you in advance.

Example : cursor":"AbpBsSIW2IKe5HycoZe-7AEPeP007M_RW_RYmHnUINzLGEBePZi8sy0snwURnd7FGcrRcH5AzrE7Ne3k0xjVR3v-D9GI1HYeLGwGNRlYTg74MMs24jpHDH72wMN5M_gD41clWHMRAq1IBZwyS-iB6AVq_mPoxc5jGnTayhaQqblAqgwuKHpXf7YcGc0te49Z_9fYcYmn61pE4d4KQAKFgqzsVW8tWn4sX7UeMhFs2U9iQe4gnBiMt93fEK7AobOueJVR7FjSmm8AJ_Jth3xPOsjQlbLDSOWKYgLRAx-pCwSS9suI9g56sio5XloQwjkXJUGPSoV7cU6VYnet4z6wiejOqY5pQBdHwN2DmijI8MvIVrOUHLJvLeGdo6zC-sLHDiMZfURkTmgDQ7YgrTZ76Wz17csw636nmr2HfsRvmOWgaf7F7UZdwar8YfDg3Kh2Il2VkhlgTweEsO5v1Zn4YRj5iGO0xzYzMBKB7gImqTD9a_FhvFZLpFhVlvfnNuX81S2CBVZQGbRIBnhg5g2h2f3YNlY7CsMlmu62F_cR36fI1oHzIHCVp0t1DvkDlcNn71JZzVJiMPf2KqVYJQRvwm6Fx_MhQ04ZEdOaSWPEWpHeyi5O6dX9TOu0yGgu_x94pZy0PMz4--x3nTKax6Y01NCfwjXjCegN_Zv5fjMOOz_TRgH4K8vMmWFttimxfoW8C97CHUjqkPIodz8Dwvv5j6AIb6A-CTaRDtyldcQOHf9_thFfRRtpkJkXeEDWgoIt5ZtI3AJZ5_6Ph-F1gmv1FvyB9Oix5heNc1LFZrtAMA3gy7pC1cHFXvwgG2redy5JsQ68Zg_thNHVM0sErzd9ReBDzzWmE2jWQgaXDjoMuArobPsRczI2JoVs7Z9yPA0A1Wp87TppjJE8hdsB2KygEwsJR_EiEhJ003xEO2GiWCN7ceybyKXHnZDwE9V5GZNg6kSQFCeCfOV-i4cASj9YFkbX2F7rXxt3BU6ACDm9Sl8xV3NYrQYb82v1UBfK0bdGXu4LdxNSgc7DZ8n5JeS8QOCAMXqJ359StxjYxuME_LRc3w"

Comment: you do know that scraping is not allowed on facebook, right? we will obviously not help you with something that is not allowed, i guess you understand.

Comment: oh sorry i search about that and i find that yes it's not allowed i didn't know that.

Because before that i see some saas who propose some functionalities that necesseraly implies web scraping on facebook